# Can a bank ask for a quicker repay of a part of a mortgage?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom

In the UK, could a bank ask you to repay quicker a part of a mortgage (or a loan guaranteed with a property) because your risk profiles increases due to the value of property going below the loan-to-value?

Comment: Typically, a financial agreement such as a credit card or mortgage contract will contain the details of how or if the rate or terms can change. Have you read the agreement word for word?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, this is a theoretical question. I am just curious whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Check the terms and conditions booklet provided with your mortgage/loan. If it isn't mentioned then they cannot do it. And it is loan-to-value, not load. Or did I miss something.

Comment: @DumbCoder - thx for typo alert, I edited that. See his comment, he just wants to know if possible, question is hypothetical, no contract to review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can, but not a part of the mortgage but the whole remaining sum. I am not so sure about loans, but I would believe they also might have the same.

> This is from Halifax -> In some circumstances (normally where you break our agreement) we may require you to pay off everything you charge, and there are a number of steps we can take, such as taking possession of your property and selling or

Comment: Thank you. I am curious, could this also happen when the bank decides that the current value of the property falls too much under the unpaid amount of the loan/mortgage?

Comment: @IonIonascu: Quite likely, in fact - if the house burns down, they'll probably claim the insurance money.